# I want a JLabel with a new getMinimumSize()

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, gridbaglayout, minimum-size

I want getMinimumSize to return weight=0 to cheat GridBagLayout.ipadx

I have tried:

```
  public class ImprovedLabel extends JLabel {
      @Override 
      public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
          return new Dimension(0, this.getHeight()); 
      } 
  }
```

But then, when I try:

```
ImprovedLabel overErrorLabel = new ImprovedLabel();
overErrorLabel.setText("Hello world!");
```

the label doesn't appear where it used to when it was a JLabel. It doesn't appear at all.
I guess I'm doing the overrride wrong. Can I have some help?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: don't cheat - learn to use LayoutManagers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0 width would make the `JLabel` invisible when the GUI is not large enough to show it fully.

Comment: I just realised that... I thought it would return 0, but not setting the width to 0.